# X-Axis labels in excel graph are showing sequence of numbers instead of actual labels

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013, charts

I have a chart as part of a template which gets plotted based on source data. Data seem to be fine but labels in x-axis are shown as sequence of numbers 1,2,3,4,etc., instead of actual labels(these change with source data).

[image: This picture should be taking names of months as x-axis lables]

Answer (score 14):

For anyone else coming here for doing scatter plots, I discovered that since scatter plots are meant to correlate two numeric axes, you have to convert to a line chart, and then just delete the lines, and then you can set the Horizontal (Category) axis labels.

Comment: Are you saying that if you need the X axis to be categories and you're using the wrong kind of chart for that, start with the right kind of chart?

Comment: I'd just never known that scatter plots were only for cases where both axes were numeric, and in this case I wanted the look of a scatter plot, as a line chart didn't make sense since I wasn't showing trends.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the chart range was correct. In that case, change the chart range (i.e. change from A2:A5 to B2:B5), hit ok, than change the datasource back to the correct row / line.

This has solved the problem every time so far for me. Not sure what the source of the issue is, but it might be the "hide" feature.

Comment: Strange. It might be a bug with excel. Thanks for the work around!

Answer (score 1):

Edit the chart data and check the entries for "Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels". If you see numbers there instead of the desired text, click Edit and select the range where the text labels are.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see the same issue with incorrect horizontal axis data being displayed. Excel will show the correct data for the horizontal axis from the data source when source data is initially chosen but then when checked in the future it reverts back to a integer sequence starting at 1. Maybe related to hide data which hides the horizontal axis but when un-hidden again, the data reverts to an integer sequence starting at 1 (not matching selected data source)