# The x-axis in a graph in excel is shown in numbers except for semesters

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am having problem to get the x-axis labels to semesters except for numbers. As shown in the picture, the variables for x axis is 2 4... 12, except for F10 S11...S15. I checked a question in this site where another person had the same problem([link](https://superuser.com/questions/1199895/x-axis-labels-in-excel-graph-are-showing-sequence-of-numbers-instead-of-actual-l)), and the solution said to edit the x axis using 'Select Data Source'. However, when I try the same thing, it doesn't allow me to edit as shown in the picture. Do I have to change something in order to enable the edit?

[image]

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1485424/edit) to 1) clarify what "...get the x-axis labels to semesters except for numbers..." means and 2) include a link to the answer you found.

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try to insert a Line Chart instead of a Scatter with Straight Lines? The X-axis values in Scatter cannot be edited.

[image]

But we can change the data range of X-axis values if using Line Chart:

[image]

Comment: That helped. Thank you!